# list slicing seems disabled in python scripting

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I'm writting a small script for the script Node of animation nodes, which I suppose uses python 3.7 like my version of Blender 2.82 does, but I'm hitting a NotImplementedError when I try to slice a list.

Here's an example code that shows this

```
import math

#recieve v1 from Blender 

for i in range(len(v1) - 1): 
    p1 = v1[i]
    p2 = v1[i + 1]

    if (p1 - p2).length > maxDist:
        middleNode = ((p1.x+p2.x)/2,(p1.y+p2.y)/2,(p1.z+p2.z)/2)

        # v1[:i] = v1[0..i] and v1[i:] = v1[i..] 
        v1 = v1[:i] + middleNode + v1[i:] 
        #v1.insert(i+1,middleNode)

    i = i + 1

v2 = v1

# send back v2 to Blender
```

I'm currently finding a workaround around this, but I didnt know where to ask about this.
I've only just started using python inside Blender and would be really disapointed if I couldnt use any kind of slicing.

Comment: What is the `type` of `v1`? In `v1 = v1[:i] + middleNode + v1[i:]`. You are asking python to concat `list` `tuple` `list` in that line

Comment: v1 is a list of vectors fed through the animation node script node, I assumed the middleNode I defined was in the same format, isn't a vector list a list of tuples ? thanks for the lead !

Comment: Yeah.... I got your problem, let me answer it in answer format

Comment: For your information, vectors have a `to_tuple()` method https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.to_tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Blender use `Vector` to describe all vector-like value in its own API, it is not only tuple but a well defined class with methods. Check the newest API here: [Blender 2.80 API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector)(or latest)

You will need to create Vector by yourself, don't wish Blender will get over-ridden parameter from tuples and other format:

[image]

So in your code:

```py
middleNode = ((p1.x+p2.x)/2,(p1.y+p2.y)/2,(p1.z+p2.z)/2) # type: tuple(float,float,float)
v1 = v1[:i] + middleNode + v1[i:] # <---- this one won't work
```

Your are asking python to stick a list of Vector to a tuple, not even a list, it will break. You can actually list it like `v1[:i] + [middleNode,]` to make python think its OK. But, the list is not all Vector but a tuple inserted between your list:

[image]

Python allow you to put any data inside a list and tuple, even they are not all same type.

So you should make your `middleNode = Vector((x,y,x))` and wrap it into a list and concat them like before.

Comment: `list.append()` `list.extend()` will also do the work

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer ! that's certainly reassuring and great to know. So happy that this works and that I know more about how Blender handles things :DD

Comment: Kindly recommend you to use `Vector.lerp()` function to do the middle node thing as described [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.lerp)

Comment: I'm having a very hard time with Animation Nodes scripting tonight, every time I do Vector.lerp(n1, n2) the software says lerp() takes exactly2 arguments (1 given) and each time I try the other syntax like so n1.Vector.lerp(n2) it tells me the Vector object has no attribute Vector. SO Ive started hardcoding everything which is a real pain

Comment: Assume you got two Vector `n1` and `n2` : `middleNode = n1.lerp( n2, 0.5 )` 0.5 is to indicate how close lerp is going to adapt n2 value, between 0 and 1. So 0.5 mean middle of n1 and n2. `Vector` is a class, not an instance. Be aware of them

Comment: Or a better format `middleNode = Vector.lerp(n1, n2, 0.5)` which is totally equivalent function call